# Docker-compose cannot find file manage.py in runserver command

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I what to dockerize my django app,
i create my Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache linux-headers libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN mkdir /DEV
WORKDIR /DEV
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . .
```

at this point i create my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypass
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    networks:
      - mynetwork

    volumes:
      - .:/DEV

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

    depends_on:
      - db
```

then i create a .dockerignore file:

```
# Ignore
.DS_Store
.idea
.venv2
__pycache__
!manage.py
*.py[cod]
*$py.class
*.so
.Python
*.log
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
geckodriver.log
golog.py
golog.pyc
log.html
media
out
output.xml
report.html
startup.sh
templates
testlibs
.dockerignore
```

well, at this point i run:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

at the end image was build correctly, but when i run:

```
docker-compose up
```

system return this error:

> web_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   core_web_1 exited with code 2

Someone can help me about the issue?

so many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try making your Dockerfile more explicit with the locations and then change your docker-compose as well:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache linux-headers libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN mkdir /DEV
WORKDIR /DEV
COPY ./requirements.txt /DEV/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /DEV/
```

```
web:
   build: .
   command: python /DEV/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
   networks:
       - mynetwork
```

Comment: python: can't open file '/DEV/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
core_web_1 exited with code 2

Comment: @ManuelSanti Bummer. At this point you need to go ahead and make a container from your image/Dockerfile, attach to it, and navigate to your /DEV folder and see if it contains the manage.py file.